# MySQL group users notifications by date and combine content

Tags: mysql

My notification table:

[image]

For example, it has 3 records:

[image]

I want to group and combine first two records (not third) by the same content_type if date_added is hour interval(if the new notification has time interval 1 hour with the last notification of this content_type they should combine). Something like this:

ID sender_id user_id type content content_type text date_added locale

8459 - 2 - 0 - friends - 122551;12517 - Will see - null - 2021-03-16 07:40:27 - null

8455 - 2 - 0 - friends - 122550 - Watched - null - 2021-03-16 07:28:00 - null

Is it possible in MySQL? Or should i re-design my table structure? Any thoughts will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: These kind of goals get dicey because time intervals are *rolling*. What I mean by that is if you have an example of 3 rows all of the same `content_type`: Row 1 has a `date_added` of 9:30 AM, Row 2 at 10 AM, and Row 3 at 10:45 AM, which rows do you group together? If you group all 3 then Row 1 and Row 3 are more than an hour apart.

Comment: All three should be combined, because notification from 10:45 has 45min interval with the latest notification (10 AM). My goal is to display in notification feed something like : userX added x items to Will see. If i won't combine them and user added 20 items in last 20 minutes, there will be 20 separate records. I also can't do this in code, because i need to limit notification count to 10 for each type

Comment: Ok that's fair. Just keep in mind if you get at least a notification within an hour of the previous one (of the same `content_type`), continuously, you could end up rolling up and combining multiple days worth of data.

Comment: I got you. I don't know how exactly others do these kind of things, but isn't this normal? IF 40 users subscribed to one in 20 minutes, and then for example each 30 min new user will subscribe for the same user for 2 days, they all should be displayed as a single record?. If i'm talking about something obvious, please point me where to go :)

Comment: It just depends on your use case. I only ask / mention, because when I've seen similar goals of rolling up `DATETIMES` by a fixed amount, when the person with the question realizes it can lead to a *cascading effect* like I pointed out above, the usual intention is to limit it by some other criteria. E.g. "*Only roll up the first two occurrences within the same hour*", so then the data would need to be ordered by some key column first before applying the hourly grouping. Just wanted to clarify your goal in such a case, but if you want to just roll them all up together, that's somewhat easier.

Comment: Can you give me an example please if i want to cascade them? Just group by hour interval, same sender_id and same content_type and combine content field

Comment: If I get a chance I'll post an answer, but don't have time at the moment, sorry. Will try to provide one when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved it using group_concat and group by hour(date_added)